# Put all the elements of a column into the same array (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql

My question is the following ;

After a first query, I have a table with a single column of bigints, for example :

```
 id 
----
  1
  2
  3
  4
```

I would like to *convert* this column into a postgresql array, which would give - according to the example - `{1,2,3,4}`.

Any ideas about how to do that ?

Thank you for all your answers and have a nice day,
best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
select array_agg(id)
from the_table;
```

If you need a specific sort order:

```
select array_agg(id order by id)
from the_table;
```